# Check occurrance of word after a particular number of lines

Tags: bash, unix

How do I check if a line starts with "WARNING: ", ignoring the first 15 lines?

To provide context, I want to use it in a bash if condition to do error processing based on a log. The way the system is setup, it gives a known warning that comes within the first 15 lines, which we need to ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tail -n +16 /var/log/syslog | grep '^WARNING'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR>15 && /^WARNING/' file

ruby -ne 'print if $.>15 && /^WARNING/' file
```